# Angular js to check input box to see if it satisfies a condition after every onkeyup action?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, onkeyup, angular-ng-if

So I am new to angular js and I understand the immediate advantage of being able input and view output seemingly in real time like this simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">      </script>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p>{{name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But now I would like to go one further and check if the user at any stage inputs say, the number 4. and if so, I'd like to output a simple message to the user.

I imagine this involves either ng-if or ng-onkeyup but the documentation about implementing these is hard to understand and I would greatly appreciate if someone with experience in this field could guide me in the right direction.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to check if the input textbox has certain value or you want to check whether user has typed character "4". So that u need to prevent or do some action on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not need keyup here. A simple `ng-if` will do the trick for you:

```
    <div ng-app="">
    <p>Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    </p>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
        <div ng-if="name==4">You entered four. This is a relevant message to four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have Fun ..!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">      </script>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-show="name!='4'">{{name}}</p><span ng-show="name=='4'">You entered 4</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to validate forms this is done nicely using ng-messages. It doesnt cover your example out of the box, but I still think that this is what you are looking for.

```
    <form name="userForm">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
    <input 
    name="name"
    ng-model="name" 
    ng-minlength="5" 
    />

    <div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
      <div ng-message="minlength">
       This is to short
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work, but they give you a very specific use case.

In a broader sense, you can use the function

```
$scope.$watch
```

in your controllers to do something "everytime that variable changes".

In your example, you can do something like [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eHmJzJT006Jn8lgSkTl2)

Remember that using $scope.$watch is a pretty expensive operation, so you should only use it when you actually NEED a constant check on something

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an answer which is more dynamic in implementation, I would suggest using the `ng-change`.

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">      </script>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="isFour()"></p>
<p>{{name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**.js**

```
//proper controller declaration
$scope.isFour = function() {
    //if you want to check that the complete input equals 4
    if($scope.name == '4') {
        //do something...
    }
    //if you want to check if the last character was 4
    if($scope.name.slice(-1) == '4') {
        //do something...
    }
    //if you want to check if it contains 4 or not 
    if($scope.name.indexOf("4") > -1) {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

**Note** that the function given to the `ng-change` executes on every change on the input box, so its a fairly expensive solution.